# lazyload jquery callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-lazyload

I currently call a function when lazyload has rendered an image. This works fine. The problem I have is that i need to access `$(this)` within the function. Is there a way of parsing this data to the function?

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/19852/

```
$("img").lazyload({
  load: equalizeHeights
});

function equalizeHeights() 
{
  //var classStr = '.'+$(this).parent('div').attr('class');
  var classStr = '.my-wrapper';
  var heights = $(classStr).map(function() {
      return $(this).height();
    }).get(),
    maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, heights);

  $('.my-wrapper').height(maxHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Function.prototype.bind()` to attach the value of `this`

Example:

```
var obj= {
 someData: "Hello"
}

function printSomeData() {
  console.log(this.someData);
}

var customFunction = printSomeData.bind(obj);

customFunction(); //withing the function, "this" is obj, so it will print "Hello"
```

So in your case I guess you can use something like

```
$("img").lazyload({
  load: equalizeHeights.bind($("img"))
});
```

(not sure what is the "this" you want to use)

Comment: Will this not bind all `$('img)` though? The reason i need `$(this)` is because I am targeting the parent class. The iddle is just a basic example, in reality there are dozens of images with different parental classes that all need equalising within class.

Comment: @steve So you're refering to the function that is passed to map(), aren't you?

Answer (score 0):

The plugin you are using actually has a callback function. example:

```
$("img.lazy").lazyload({
    load : function(elements_left, settings) {
        console.log(this, elements_left, settings);
        $(document).trigger("something");
    }
});
```

In your case you'd use it like this:

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/19856/

```
$("img").lazyload({
  effect: "fadeIn",
  threshold: 300,
  failure_limit: 10,
  load: function(elements_left, settings) {
    equalizeHeights(this);
  }
});

function equalizeHeights(ele) 
{
  var classStr = '.'+$(ele).parent('div').attr('class');
  var heights = $(classStr).map(function() {
      return $(this).height();
    }).get(),
    maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, heights);

  $('.my-wrapper').height(maxHeight);
}
```

I assume that is the use case you were after.